# How to convert four uint16_t to double float IEEE754?

Tags: esp8266, data-type, float

I am working in a Modbus project where I have to read modbus Holding and Input registers using ESP8266, I am using ModbusMaster232 library. I returns a response buffer array of uint16_t. I need to convert the uint16_t to double precision float. A quick test in ESP8266 shows double datatype in ESP8266 stores 8 bytes.Does anybody know how to convert four uint16_t to double in Arduino. If so please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code fragment for converting a uint16_t. Expand this to work with your array of ints from the library.
Remember that on Arduino, - Uno and Mega, at least - doubles are implemented as floats. You won't get the precision you might be expecting.

```
double xAsDouble;    // ** only float precision despite 'double' declaration
uint16_t xAsInt;

xDouble = xInt;      // the compiler knows how to make this conversion.
```

Update: After re-reading your question, I realize you're using an ESP8266. My comments about Uno's float precision may not apply.

Update 2: After some discussion, I've learned that the Modbus return is not 4 integers, but a double being passed as 4 words, which need to be reassembled to recreate the original double. The solution will depend on the order in which the words comprising the original double are sent.

Update 3: I suggested the OP try using this general scheme:

```
// A union lets you look at memory as either (in this case) 4 ints or 1 double
union {
   uint16_t data_out[4];
   double x;
} buffer;

// Assign the data from modbus using the 'int' way of viewing menmory.
// Note I might have the ordering wrong but this is the idea:
buffer.data_out[i] = data_in[i];
```

Then reading 'buffer.x' would get the 4 words of memory as a double.

... After trying both orderings, the OP reports he is obtaining the expected result,

Comment: Thanks for reply @JRobert but I am using **uint16_t array** with 4 elements not a single uint16_t variable, I have to group this _four 16 bit containers to a single 64 bit container_ representing **IEEE754 float variable**. Could you elaborate how the code would do that

Comment: Do you understand how to use a `for()` loop to execute one or more statements over the members (items) in an array?

Comment: Do you mean
`uint16_t data_in={2121,1233,3435,2433};
double data_out=0;
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
{
data_out = data_out | data_in[i]<<16;
}`

Comment: Yes - please see my edited comment above. You would do the same as in my example, but using [i] to address each of the ints and floats.

Comment: Is that code correct @JRobert ?

Comment: Take out the left shift - all you need is a simple assignment. The compiler knows from your declarations that 'data_out' is double and 'data_in' is uint_16, and how to assign one to the other, including the proper conversion.

Comment: Will try as you said in my ESP8266 board and revert back @JRobert

Comment: As I expected I am getting the value of last element in array with decimal @JRobert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107093/discussion-between-mr-b-and-jrobert).